# stack with template in C++

Tags: templates, stack

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Stack
{
public:
// Use user defined template class for stack push
    template <class S, class D>
    void stk_push(S &stk, D data)
    {
        stk.push(data);
    }

// Use user defined template class for stack pop
    template <class S, class D>
    D stk_pop(S &stk)
    {
        return(stk.pop(S));
    }
};

int main ()
{
    stack<int> si;  // si is stack of int elements

    stack<float> sf; // sf is stack of float elements

    stack<string> ss; // ss is stack of strings


    Stack S;

    S.stk_push(si, 333);
    cout << endl << (int)S.stk_pop(si);  // test it

    S.stk_push(sf,1.234);
    cout << endl << (float)S.stk_pop(sf);  // test it

     S.stk_push(ss,"Efraim");
    cout << endl << (string)S.stk_pop(ss);  // tes`enter code here`t it

}
```

I need to find why the S.stk_pop() call is not OK.
when trying to build I got the following errors:
Error   1   error C2783: 'D Stack::stk_pop(S &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'D'

Answer (score 0):

The definition for [std::stack::pop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) declares it as:

```
void pop();
```

So you have a few errors, the primary one being that you are attempting to pass an argument to `pop`:

```
return(stk.pop(S));
```

(Note that `S` is also type and not a parameter, so even if `pop` accepted an argument this would still be incorrect.)

And the second being that the return type of your `stk_pop` function is declared as:

```
template <class S, class D>
D stk_pop(S &stk)
{
    return(stk.pop(S));
}
```

Where the compiler has no way to determine what `D` is. If you're using a more advanced C++ compiler, you can let it infer `void` by using `auto`:

```
template <class S>
auto stk_pop(S &stk)
{
    return(stk.pop());
}
```

Or if you have C++11 only, you can use a trailing return type:

```
template <class S>
auto stk_pop(S &stk) -> decltype(stk.pop())
{
    return(stk.pop());
}
```

But you're probably safe with simply specifying the return type to be `void`:

```
template <class S>
void stk_pop(S &stk)
{
    stk.pop();
}
```

Comment: Hello I updated my code with:                                                      template <class S>
auto stk_pop(S &stk)
{
    return(stk.pop());
}                                                                                                                                            but I got error: Error 1 error C3551: expected a trailing return type

Comment: Most likely you cannot compile C++14, or you haven't told your compiler to. How are you compiling, and with what compiler?

Comment: @user3879626: Then you cannot use the C++14 syntax with only `auto` as return type. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) VS2012 does support trailing return types, so you'll want the `auto stk_pop(S& stk) -> decltype(stk.pop())` version I posted.

Comment: Hello, I changed to:                                                                            template <class S>
 auto stk_pop(S &stk) -> decltype(stk.pop())
 {
  return(stk.pop());
 }                                                                                                                                           but I got now error on the cout << S.stk_pop(si);                                      Error 1 error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: In `main` you are trying to print the result of `stk_pop`. You cannot, because the value is `void`

Comment: But I defined the stk_pop with auto not void ?

Comment: `auto` with training return syntax allows the compiler to deduce `void` as the return type.

Comment: What should i fo to print the value after stk.pop ?

Comment: Please consult the documentation I linked to.

Comment: What  is the link for documentaion ?